# Can't import Arraylist from two classes...what now?

Tags: java, class, import

I am new to Java and found out a bit late I cannot import an `ArrayList` from more than one class.

Build it with only one class (`BlackLabel`) and the `CustomAdapter` worked fine. Now I want to add a second brand (`Castle`) but I found out I can only import one static. Maybe you guys can be so kind and help me with another way to add more than one brand to use the same adapter.

Here is my adapter: (just the beginning)

```
import static com.example.android.sab.BlackLabel.modelArrayList;
//import static com.example.android.sab.CastleLager.modelArrayList;

/**
* Created by Carel on 2017/08/15.
*/
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

   private LayoutInflater inflater;
   private Context ctx;

   public CustomAdapter(Context ctx) {
      inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
      this.ctx = ctx;
   }

   @Override
   public CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
      MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

      return holder;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) modelArrayList.get(position).getBrand());
      holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber()));
      holder.tvPallet_size.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getPallet_size()));
      holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber2()));
      holder.tvPallets.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber()));
      holder.tvCases.setText(String.valueOf(modelArrayList.get(position).getNumber2()));
   }
```

And here is BlackLabel cass which was the first one:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import static com.example.android.sab.CastleLager.modelArrayList;

public class BlackLabel extends brands {
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   //private String modelArrayList;
   //private Context ctx;
   public static ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;
   private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
   //private Button btnnext;

   public String[] brandlist = new String[] {
      "Black Label 340ml NRB (85023)",
      "Black Label 330ml Cans (85736)",
      "Black label 500ml Cans (85023)",
      "Black Label 440ml NRB (86798)",
      "Black Label 330ml RB (85556)",
      "Black Label 750ml RB (85021)",
      "Black Label 340ml NRB 12 Pack (87009)",
      "Black Label 500ml Cans 12 Pack (85022)"
   };

   public int[] pallet_size = {84, 127, 81, 80, 120, 70, 132, 90};
   //int palletsize = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(pallet_size));

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.order_by_brand);
      setTitle("Black Label");
      recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
      //btnnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
      modelArrayList = getModel();
      customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
   }

   private ArrayList<Model> getModel() {
      ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         Model model = new Model();
         model.setNumber(0);
         model.setNumber2(0);
         model.setBrand(brandlist[i]);
         model.setPallet_size(pallet_size[i]);
         list.add(model);
      }
      return list;
   }
}
```

and now I want to use an arraylist from a second class:

```
public class CastleLager extends brands {

   private RecyclerView recyclerView;
   //private String modelArrayList;
   //private Context ctx;
   public static ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;
   private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
   //private Button btnnext;
   public String[] castlebrandlist = new String[] {
      "Castle Lager 340ml NRB (85023)",
      "Castle Lager 330ml Cans (85736)",
      "Castle Lager 500ml Cans (85023)",
      "Castle Lager 440ml NRB (86798)",
      "Castle Lager 330ml RB (85556)",
      "Castle Lager 750ml RB (85021)",
      "Castle Lager 340ml NRB 12 Pack (87009)",
      "Castle Lager 500ml Cans 12 Pack (85022)"
   };
}
```

I know its probably very basic, but as I said I'm very new to java and just can't get my head around where to start. Thank you.

Comment: You can import only one and you have to use a fully qualified name for the other, e.g. `holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) com.example.android.sab.CastleLager.modelArrayList.get(position).getBrand());`

Comment: Or just import the classes, and use `Class.field` syntax EG: `CastleLager.modelArrayList`...

Comment: And talking about naming: read about Java naming conventions. Class names start upper case always. So `extends brand` sounds wrong, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simply: avoid "relative" names.

Meaning: when you have x.y.Z and x2.y2.Z, then do not use the name `Z` within your source code, but the fully qualified names `x.y.Z` or `x2.y2.Z`.

Yes, that is sometimes inconvenient, but the only choice you have here. Other languages, such as python allow you to "rename" imported things, but Java doesn't. The only option to avoid name collisions when two classes have the same name is to switch to fully qualified names.

And just to be sure: the **real** problem in your code is the fact that you want to **allow** "read/write" access to a **field** of a class in different places. You see - fields represent the **inner state** of your classes. You strive to **hide** such information from the outside world - because that is an implementation detail that nobody outside should care or know about.

So the real answer here is to step back and consider a more robust design that is *not* based on exposing a field to the outside world!

Comment: GhostCat I think you're right. I might have to take a few steps back. As I said I'm new to Java and its a bit of a downer to do all this work then only to realist you've got to start over again. Thank you anyway.